# Solr multiValued field. Wrong value returned [B@6ad21538

Tags: solr

I have the problem when solr put some unexpected value in field.

**in schema.xml**

```
<field name="country_ids" type="string" multiValued="true" stored="true" indexed="true" />
```

**in media-jdbc.xml**

```
<field column="country_ids" splitBy="\|" />
```

and query returns **NULL** or **2|3|8|9|3**  for this field.  (all query is to big and works perfectly)

When i do query in browser.

the field holds strange value:

```
<arr name="country_ids">
    <str>[B@6ad21538</str>
</arr>
```

What I'm missing?

Solr version 3.5

Comment: How are you indexing your data? Through a Java program? DataImportHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So i was using this query for importing:

```
(select group_concat(distinct mmpc.mediacountry_id separator '|') from media_media_production_countries mmpc where mmpc.media_id=m.id) as country_ids
```

After edited it slightly I've got right results.
Changed it to:

```
convert((select group_concat(distinct mmpc.mediacountry_id separator '|') from media_media_production_countries mmpc where mmpc.media_id=m.id) USING latin1) as country_ids
```

If you noutice i added `conver(**MY_STATEMENT** USING latin1)`

But steel cant explain why. I would appreciate if someone give me an explanation.

Comment: What you get back from your query is a Java Object which doesn't extend the `toString` method. You get back what the default implementation of the `toString` method returns. I guess it depends on the type of the column, which is not a simple String. What type is it?

Comment: Actually `group_concat` returning string (i believe). So it depends on what it returns.

Comment: I thought the same but you didn't have a String back, otherwise you would have seen the string value in Solr.